# VWD 2008 Express : where can i set absolute positioning as a default?

Tags: css-position, visual-web-developer, vwdexpress

So when I used Visual Web Developer 2005 Express edition, in the ribbon there was a menu option for "Layout", which you could go through and select positioning and set absolute to default.

I am using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express now, and I see that you can select format from the menu bar, and set position > absolute, for each individual control that you add to the design surface, but is there a place I can just set absolute as the default, like in 2005?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0):

Take **Tools > Options > HTML Designer > CSS Styling >**

Check '*Change positioning to absolute for controls added using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop*'.

Then, in design page, select form, then in menu..
**Format > Position > Positioning Style >** 
Select '*Absolute*'.

Now you will be able to absolute positioning the components...

Please mark as answer if you found this helpful!